# In jmeter, how can I keep a websocket connection for later use

Tags: websocket, jmeter

I just have a load test in JMeter, in the test, the client will send several requests in few seconds. But I find a problem when the client makes a new request, the JMeter will close the former connection and create a new connection, I just want to reuse the former connection to send a request to the WebSocket server.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAagH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just tick `use existing connection` box in your WebSocket Samplers and the connection established by the `WebSocket Open Connection` sampler will be re-used

[image]

I believe the connection doesn't survive [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) iterations (it's basically re-established when Open Connection sampler is executed 2nd time, if you need to repeat the request more than once - either go for [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) or put the Open Connection sampler under the [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)

More information: [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Follow your suggestion, I use [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) to reuse the connection